# How to determine the location of the end (pixel coordinates or otherwise) of a Progressbar?

Tags: android

Simply put, I have a progress bar with text ON it, like so:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"    
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_on_progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressbar"
    android:text="text"
/>
```

The thing is, I would like to have "text" only appear directly to the left of the current progress. So, it would be right justified to the current endpoint. Any ideas on how to do this? So the text moves alongside the progress.

So is there a way to find the pixel coordinates of the current endpoint of the displayed progress? That way I can put the textview there dynamically.

Or is there a way to actually access the progressbar.xml itself to edit this in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the endpoint of the displayed progress from the complete width of the view and the current progress. Easy example: If the view is 400 pixels wide and progress is 50%, the endpoint will be 50% of 400, which is 200 (plus left position of the progress view of course, e.g. margin or padding ...)

Comment: How do I set the margins or position of textview after I have the desired width?

Comment: Margins can be set using the LayoutParams of the View, but I think it might be easier to change the padding.